# Whats make different in below Jquery code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, load

I'm working with on developing one of the social networking site and its having some notification features in left panel.
Whenever any user have played a game it will automatically change the number of notification count.

For that i have using below code line.

```
jQuery('#count_id').load('mypage.php');
```

But it will retrieve me whole site content with header,footer and content area in the response text, which is wrong as per my requirements.

but if i used below code of line

```
jQuery('#count_id').load('mypage.php #count_id');
```

then it will retrieve me a real count but add another div in between the original,

Original html:

```
<div id="count_id" class="notify">2</div>
```

and Code after retrieving response:

```
<div id="count_id" class="notify">
 <div id="count_id" class="notify">1</div>
</div>
```

which is also not as expected. count are right but i don't want to add new div inside a original one.

What should i need to change in my code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
jQuery('#count_id').load('mypage.php #count_id > *');
```

That would bring only the DOM childs (the content)

Answer (score 2):

Because this is how it works. Also it enables you to attach events to the element you load and delegate them inside this element (so new elements can also benefit from attached JavaScript events) - see `.delegate()`.

If you want to replace the element, you can try the following:

```
jQuery.get('mypage.php', function(data){
    jQuery('#count_id').replace(jQuery(data).find('#count_id'));
}, 'html');
```

I did not test it, but it should work.

Ivan Castellanos is however right. According to the documentation, you can provide any selector after the first space in the `.load()`'s parameter.

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve count_id, you can directly get the html value in the div like this:

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() 
    {
        countVal = $("#count_id").html(); //returns the html content inside the div, which is the count value
        countVal = parseInt(countVal); //This will convert the string to type integer
    });
    </script>
```

Note: 
If you want increase the count and update the div value, you can add the following lines:

```
countVal++;
$("#count_id").html(countVal);
```